# what is attrs.get in Django REST serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to understand and learn Django serializers.  The give an example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Given a dictionary of deserialized field values, either update
        an existing model instance, or create a new model instance.
        """
        if instance is not None:
            instance.email = attrs.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.content = attrs.get('content', instance.content)
            instance.created = attrs.get('created', instance.created)
            return instance
        return Comment(**attrs)
```

I can't figure out where 'attrs.get' comes from, or what it does.

Even less clear are the lines like this:

```
            instance.email = attrs.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.content = attrs.get('content', instance.content)
            instance.created = attrs.get('created', instance.created)
```

Which feels like a snake eating its tail...if 'instance' already has an 'email' attribute, what is the point of what looks like looking it up and then setting it to itself?

Comment: Because it allows overriding that value with whatever is in `attrs`.

Comment: you can read it as: if attrs has key 'email' update it for instance other way use current value for instance.

Comment: I was being stupid and (1) looking for some import that provided a bunch of methods under the namespace 'attrs', and (2) not realizing '.get' can take a default.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at function argument

```
def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
```

it's require a dictionary and instance of Comment models . the attrs is a standard python dictionary that form `{'email':'whatever', ...}`

```
attrs.get('email', instance.email)
```

return email if exist else return `instance.email`

```
return Comment(**attrs)
```

this line of code means if you do not pass a existing model to function as instance 
it will constract a new model based on attrs (dictionary) and return that one . this is equal to

```
return Comment(email ='email' ,content="" , created="" )
```